# Newsstand resume download after the App closed by user Fully

Tags: ios, newsstand-kit

How do we resume a download after the user quits the app, not just put into background?

My code looks like this to start the download initially, I want to be able to identify here as to if the issue can be resumed.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *nkRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                                 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                             timeoutInterval:30.0];
        NKLibrary *library = [NKLibrary sharedLibrary];
        NKIssue *issue = [library addIssueWithName:[downloadInfo objectForKey:kPackageID] date:[NSDate date]];

        [[NKLibrary sharedLibrary] setCurrentlyReadingIssue:[[NKLibrary sharedLibrary] issueWithName:[downloadInfo objectForKey:kPackageID]]];
        NKAssetDownload *asset = [issue addAssetWithRequest:nkRequest];
        [asset setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:info,@"info", nil]];   
        [asset downloadWithDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it seems to be quite simple.  The way I am doing (and how it seems Apple says to do it) is by putting the following code in the AppDelegate method application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
// Get the Library
NKLibrary *nkLib = [NKLibrary sharedLibrary];

// Loop through all 'queued' NKAssetDownloads and resume with a delegate
for(NKAssetDownload *asset in [nkLib downloadingAssets])
{
    [asset downloadWithDelegate:yourDownloadDelegate];
}
```

That should be all you need to do.  This was briefly mentioned at WWDC 2011 under Session 504.  That video and slides are good Newsstand-Kit references.  I would highly recommend you watch/read that.  It helped me a lot.  Good luck!