# Apple Newsstand Download Complete Notification

Tags: ios, newsstand-kit

I have a newsstand application which provides the downloads through the NKNewsstandKit.

My Problem is that when i start downloading a asset & terminate the application, it downloads in the background perfectly. It also invoke the application in background mode. But i did not get the event connectionDidFinishDownloading:

Does anyone even have an idea, how i can get the event & process my assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start downloading while the app is running and then terminate the app you won't get any asset download delegate methods called (there is a launch option `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsNewsstandDownloadsKey` which I expected in this case but I've never seen this happen). The best solution is when the user starts the app, resume downloading each of the assets in `[[NKLibrary sharedLibrary] downloadingAssets]` and you should get a `connectionDidFinishDownloading` for each that has already downloaded. Be sure to do this in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method on the main thread or the assets will be deleted.

Also see [Detecting background app launch in Xcode to debug a Newsstand app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898307/detecting-background-app-launch-in-xcode-to-debug-a-newsstand-app) and [Newsstand resume download after the App closed by user Fully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583652/newsstand-resume-download-after-the-app-closed-by-user-fully)

Comment: Although this answer is accepted but what I am observing is different. Most of the time when my downloads completes I get connectionDidResumeDownloading called where I process (unzip) and move  it to contentUrl of NKIssue. And sometime the download pauses in background (its all up to NS framework) and we should resume such downloads from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.